# How to diff large files on Linux

Tags: linux, diff

I'm getting a `diff: memory exhausted` error when trying to diff two 27 GB files that are largely similar on a Linux box with CentOS 5 and 4 GB of RAM. This is a known problem, it seems.

I would expect there to be an alternative for such an essential utility, but I can't find one. I imagine the solution would have to use temporary files rather than memory to store the information it needs.

- I tried to use `rdiff` and `xdelta`, but they are better for showing the changes between two files, like a patch, and are not that useful for inspecting the differences between two files.
- Tried [VBinDiff](http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/), but it is a visual tool which is better for comparing binary files. I need something that can pipe the differences to STDOUT like regular `diff`.
- There are a lot of other utilities such as `vimdiff` that only work with smaller files.
- I've also read about Solaris `bdiff` but I could not find a port for Linux.

Any ideas besides splitting the file into smaller pieces? I have 40 of these files so trying to avoid the work of breaking them up.

Comment: what version of xdelta did you try? xdelta3 or xdelta1?

Comment: It was version 1.1.4. Does xdelta3 provide different functionality? I just checked the online doc and it still seems to be about providing "deltas".

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/516289/tool-for-diffing-large-files

Comment: See also this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77259/27186

Answer (score 16):

`cmp` does things byte-by-byte, so it probably won't run out of memory (just tested it on two 7 GB files) -- but you might be looking for more detail than a list of "files *X* and *Y* differ at byte *x*, line *y*". If the similarities of your files are offset (e.g., file *Y* has an identical block of text, but not at the same location), you can pass offsets to `cmp`; you could probably turn it into a resynchronizing compare with a small script.

Aside: In case anyone else lands here when looking for a way to confirm that two directory structures (containing very large files) are identical:
`diff --recursive --brief` (or `diff -r -q` for short, or maybe even `diff -rq`) will work and not run out of memory.

Comment: nice, I think -q is the key here, somehow not having it can require diff to put the whole file (or at least whole lines) into memory...

Answer (score 6):

I found this [link](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2005-February/075901.html)

> diff -H might help, or you can try
>   installing the textproc/2bsd-diff port
>   which apparently doesn't try to load
>   the files into RAM, so it can work on
>   large files more easily.

I'm not sure if you tried those two options or if they might work for you.  Good luck.

Comment: Does this help for anybody out there?  For me, same failure...

Comment: For anyone wondering: `diff -H` is an undocumented and deprecated alias for `diff --speed-large-files`.

Comment: This answer doesn't help. This is a linux question, and to install 2bsd-diff you would have to port it first. After you [found a source](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/UCB/2.11BSD/). And [patched it](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/tree/master/textproc/2bsd-diff/files). Possible, but unlikely a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are identical (same length) except for a few byte values, you can use a script like following (`w` is the number of bytes per line to hexdump, adjust to your display width):

```
w=12;
while read -ru7 x && read -ru8 y;
do
  [ ".$x" = ".$y" ] || echo "$x | $y";
done 7< <(od -vw$w -tx1z FILE1) 8< <(od -vw$w -tx1z FILE2) > DIFF-FILE1-FILE2 &

less DIFF-FILE1-FILE2
```

It's not very fast, but does the job.

Answer (score 1):

If the files have the same number of lines and differ by the content of a few of them, use the following command.  Substitute `\a` (alert) with any other character that does not occur within the files.

```
paste -d $'\a' file1 file2 | awk -F$'\a' '$1 != $2'
```

This works by pairing the lines of the two files and then comparing each pair.

Comment: This was a great help... I extended it for my needs, in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

So, not exactly the OPs problem, but a related problem is that you have two large database dumps, each insert/record on its own row, but varying differences in floating-point implementation result in numbers that are off by [some IEEE error](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Thanks to the [answer provided](https://superuser.com/a/1543129/437093) by @Diomidis, and a sprawling one-line awk script show below, we get a full functioning, efficient fuzzy-differ.

Add the text below to some script directory as `fuzzy-compare.awk`, tune the parameters in the BEGIN section as needed (locale-specific, debugging modes, etc), then pipe the output of `paste` into it:

```
paste -d $'\a' file1 file2 | awk -f fuzzy-compare.awk
```

Sample output:

```
Line 1 diffs found so far: 1 here at field: 4
75747358        1       53      2011-03-29 23:00:00+00  7.428
75747358        1       53      2011-03-28 23:00:00+00  7.428

Line 2 diffs found so far: 2 here at field: 4
75747359        1       53      2011-03-29 23:30:00+00  5.757
75747359        1       53      2011-03-29 23:30:00+01  5.757

Line 3 diffs found so far: 3 here at field: 3
75747360        1       53      2011-03-30 00:00:00+00  6.739
75747360        1       54      2011-03-30 00:00:00+00  6.74

Line 5 diffs found so far: 4
75747362        1       53      2011-03-30 01:00:00+00  6.736   extra-field
75747362        1       53      2011-03-30 01:00:00+00  6.73599999999999977
```

With diff showing:

```
# diff sample.sql sample2.sql
1,3c1,3
< 75747358      1       53      2011-03-29 23:00:00+00  7.428
< 75747359      1       53      2011-03-29 23:30:00+00  5.757
< 75747360      1       53      2011-03-30 00:00:00+00  6.739
---

> 75747358      1       53      2011-03-28 23:00:00+00  7.428
> 75747359      1       53      2011-03-29 23:30:00+01  5.757
> 75747360      1       54      2011-03-30 00:00:00+00  6.74
5,13c5,13
< 75747362      1       53      2011-03-30 01:00:00+00  6.736   extra-field
< 75747363      1       53      2011-03-30 01:30:00+00  7.576
< 75747364      1       53      2011-03-30 02:00:00+00  6.789
< 75747365      1       53      2011-03-30 02:30:00+00  6.386e+2
< 75747366      1       53      2011-03-30 03:00:00+00  6.016E-2
< 75747367      1       53      2011-03-30 03:30:00+00  6.336
< 75747368      1       53      2011-03-30 04:00:00+00  6.1
< 75747374      1       53      2011-03-30 07:00:00+00  5.9412
< 75747375      1       53      2011-03-30 07:30:00+00  6.137803249
---
> 75747362      1       53      2011-03-30 01:00:00+00  6.73599999999999977
> 75747363      1       53      2011-03-30 01:30:00+00  7.576e+10
> 75747364      1       53      2011-03-30 02:00:00+00  6.789e-10
> 75747365      1       53      2011-03-30 02:30:00+00  6.38600000000000012e+2
> 75747366      1       53      2011-03-30 03:00:00+00  6.01600000000000001E-2
> 75747367      1       53      2011-03-30 03:30:00+00  6.3360000000000003
> 75747368      1       53      2011-03-30 04:00:00+00  6.0999999999999993
> 75747374      1       53      2011-03-30 07:00:00+00  5.94099999999999984
> 75747375      1       53      2011-03-30 07:30:00+00  6.13780324900000007
```

Code below (duplicated to a github gist: https://gist.github.com/otheus/92162e3a764d2697c3272b98b2663a94).

```
#!/bin/awk -f 
## Awk script to compare to SQL (postgres) dumps for which each line of input is a row
## and has been preprocessed by 
##   paste -d $'\a' file1 file2 
## The BEL symbol is used by this program to quickly split the input
##   
## Sometimes, numbers differ by some kind of rounding error / floating-point implementation
## Ignore that error by subtracting the two values and seeing if they are < maxdiff,
##     maxdiff = 1 / (10 ^ (length-after-decimal-point(shortest-value)) 
## Consider:
##   4.2  vs 4.19998
## The shortest number is 4.2, its length is 

## Notes:
##   d is the global *d*iff counter
##   p is the *p*osition / field that first had a difference
##   i is a loop variable,usually current field
##   L is the array of fields from the current line of the *L*eft-file
##   R is  "    "    "    "     "   "    "  "    "   "  "  *R*ight-file
##   clhs is the number of fields in L
##   crhs is the number of fields in R

BEGIN { 
  FS="\a";
  DECIMAL_SEP=".";
  FIELD_SEP="\t";  # for postgresql; for mysql, maybe ", ";
  MAX_DIFFS=10;
  DEBUG=0;
  # Efficiently fill out our table of maximum tolerances of values
  Maxdiffs[1] = 0.1;
  for (i=2; i<31; ++i)
    Maxdiffs[i] = Maxdiffs[i-1] / 10;
  p=-1; # everything starts out fine.
}

# if -v start=...., skip until that line
NR < (0 + start) { next } 

# When pairs don't match, investigate further...
("_" $1) != ("_" $2) {
    if (DEBUG>1) print "Line",NR ": Input lines differed somehow. Investigating...";
    p=0;  # p is field# where difference was found; 0 means whole line
    # split each half into tab-delimited fields
    clhs=split($1,L,FIELD_SEP);
    crhs=split($2,R,FIELD_SEP); 

    if (clhs == crhs) { 
    if (DEBUG>1) print "Line",NR ": Same number of tokens in each line, delimited by '" FIELD_SEP "'";
        ## compare field by field
    p = -1;  # if we don't set p in the loop below, no real differences

    # Compare each field, until a difference is found
    for (i=1; i<=clhs && p<0; ++i) {  
        # Hint: force this compare to be string-based
        if (("_" L[i]) != ("_" R[i])) { 
        if (DEBUG>1) print "Line",NR ": Field",i,"differs somehow";

        ## They differ... but are they numbers?
        if ( \
          L[i] ~ /^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+([eE][-+][0-9]+)?$/ && \
          R[i] ~ /^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+([eE][-+][0-9]+)?$/ \
        ) {  
            # both fields are floating-point numbers, compare loosely

            # strip exponent part
            sub(/[eE].*/,"",L[i]);sub(/[eE].*/,"",R[i]); 
            # determine precision of shortest value
            precision=( \
                length(L[i]) < length(R[i]) ?  \
            length(L[i]) - index(L[i],DECIMAL_SEP) :  \
            length(R[i]) - index(R[i],DECIMAL_SEP)    \
            ); 
            # look up the maxdiff from our table
            maxdiff=Maxdiffs[precision]; 

            diff=(L[1] - R[1]); 
            if (diff > maxdiff || diff < -maxdiff) {
            if (DEBUG) print "Line",NR ": Numbers differed at",i,"between",L[i],"and",R[i],"differing more than",maxdiff;
            p=i;
            }
            else {
            if (DEBUG) print "Line",NR ": Numbers differed at",i,"between",L[i],"and",R[i],"but differed less than",maxdiff;
            }
        } 
        else {
          if (DEBUG) print "Line",NR ": Strings or ints differed at",i,"between",L[i],"and",R[i];
          p=i;
        }
        }
        else { 
          if (DEBUG) print "Line",NR ": No differences found";
        }
    } 
    }
    # else, field count is different, so whole line is.
    else { 
      if (DEBUG) print "Line",NR ": Number of fields in line differ";
    }
}

p>=0 { 
    ++d;  # bump total diffs count
    # Output a little header for each non-matching records
    print "Line",NR,"diffs found so far:",d,(p ? "here at field: "  p : "" ); 
    # Output the lines that didnt match
    print $1; print $2; print ""; 
    p=-1;
}

# Progress counter
NR % 100000 == 0 { print "Line",NR } 
d > MAX_DIFFS { exit(1);}
```

Note, the above code was a 1-liner prior to publication.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for all types of files, but if your files have a regular structure to them you may be able to split them into smaller chunks and `diff` the chunks individually.

For example:

```
csplit large-file.txt '/separator pattern/' '{*}'
```

Caveat: this only works if your file has something you can use a separator without producing hundreds of small files and where the smaller chunks are still comparable.