# Tool for diffing large files

Tags: linux, shell, memory, diff

When I use "diff" to find the difference between two large data files,

```
diff A.txt B.txt > dif.info
```

it is output:

```
diff:memory exhausted
```

or add the argument "-H"

```
diff -H A.txt B.txt > dif.info
```

it also got the same message:

```
diff:memory exhausted
```

The size are about 1.5GB.
How to compare large files ? Any other tools or solutions ?
my PC: Redhat5.4 OS, 4GB memory.
Thanks.

Comment: The most simple solution would be to add more RAM (which is really cheap these days), assuming a 64 bits Linux. Otherwise try to split the files in smaller chunks. Perhaps add some more swap.

Comment: any other software or script to handle large file?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, what do the files look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea would be to use `split` on both files and compare each chunk. 
It will not be exactly the same, but it all depends on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try installing the textproc/2bsd-diff port

http://www.freshports.org/textproc/2bsd-diff/

Comment: but how to install it?

Comment: Google is a good friend to know. :)  http://dir.filewatcher.com/d/FreeBSD/5.5-release/i386/2bsd-diff-2.11.tbz.19756.html