# Comparing two large files in Linux without exhausting memory

Tags: linux, command-line, diff

I am using `diff file1 file2` and getting memory exhausted exception. file1 and file 2 are 10 GB each.

I tried `diff --speed-large-files file1 file2` but that didn't work.

How can I compare two files file1 and file2 and see what changed in file2 and write the changed content on file2 to another file?

Answer (score 0):

Gnu `diff` requires to be able to load the input files into RAM.

According to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77251/is-there-bdiff-1-in-linux/77259#77259), `bdiff` is available as part of the [heirloom toolchest](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html) and doesn't require reading the files into RAM. You'll have to compile it yourself though as it doesn't seem to be available on most Linux distros.

Other questions on [CSV files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350631/diff-two-large-csv-files-each-90gb-and-output-to-another-csv?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [large files](https://superuser.com/questions/174283/how-to-diff-large-files-on-linux) have alternative solutions but none of them seem to quite do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to break the files into parts and compare them in order.  For instance, split out each 10 GB file to about 100 numbered hundred-megabyte files.  Run the diff on the files in order, comparing outputA01 to outputB01, then outputA02 to outputB02, and son on.
Related question :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/break-a-large-file-into-smaller-pieces